# Android App crash when clicking on button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a HomeActivity which has a login and register button. When clicking on the register button the app crashes. I have posted the HomeActivity Java code where the onclick method is and the Manifest. The app just stops working, I cannot find the error

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
//views  
Button hRegisterBtn, hLoginBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //init views
    hRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    hLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

    //handle register button click
    hRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // start RegisterActivity
         startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));

        }
    });

}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--Internet Permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjektSplashScreen">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Home"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please add error trace to understand what the error refers to?

Comment: there is no error, the app just stops working. I have a splash screen that goes to the homeactivity where my register button is. When I click on the button the app stops working

Comment: _"there is no error, the app just stops working"_. That doesn't sound very likely. In any case, it looks like you haven't declared your `RegisterActivity` in the manifest.

Comment: I mean there might be a error but I dont get it shown. Can you explain to me how I declare it in the manifest ?

Comment: do i just use the activity tag and give it a label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your Manifest file that you have registered `RegisterActivity`. You need to declare every activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, like so:

```js
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjektSplashScreen">
    <!--Some of your other manifest code-->
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="Register"/>
    <activity android:name=".path.to.your.OtherActivity"
        android:label="Other"/>
    <!--Some of your other manifest code-->
</application
```

Answer (score 0):

Define RegisterActivity to your Manifest

```
<!--Internet Permission-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjektSplashScreen">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Home"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</application>
```